# Is it posible to modify packets that creats by request python module?

Tags: python, python-3.x, web, request, packet

Let's say we have the following piece of python code

`response = requests.get('https://webserver:8000', verify='server.pem', timeout=10,proxies=dict(https='socks5h://test:test@proxyserver:1080'))`

Is it possible to modify the web packages created by this request and send them to their destination?

I tried to use scapy, but it didn't help

Comment: "*I tried to use scapy*" Please provide an [mre] of this attempt, along with an explanation of why *specifically* it didn't meet your requirements, per [ask]. What is it you want to modify in packets that are being sent? What's your use case? Generally speaking, there is a particularly limited set of circumstances in which you'd actually have to override the way packets are created by your OS' core networking stack/kernel, and nothing in your question or your line of code you've provided that suggests your use case requires the complexity of such specialized handling.

Comment: Depends on what you mean by "modify". `requests.get` does two separate things: it creates a request, then submits it to the given URL. You can do these two steps manually, so that you can modify the request yourself before submitting it. See https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/advanced/#prepared-requests, for example.

Comment: @chepner I need to modify the tls package created by this request, is it possible?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.